# How do I queue asynchronous function calls in WinJS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sqlite, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm using [SQLite3-WinRT](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT) for my WinJS project but have recently run into the problem that some queries may lock the database.

The quick and dirty method would be to wait an arbitrary time and simply try again (due to the fact that this is a single-user app).

An example of such a query looks like this:

```js
var sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Table;";
SQLite3JS.openAsync(path_to_db)
.then(function (db) {
  return db.runAsync(sql_query)
  .then(function () {
      db.close();
    }, function (error) {
      db.close();
      console.log(error)
  });
});
```

So, basically, I need make the asynchronous calls wait their turn. How do I do this best given the constraint that the access to the database has to look like the function above?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an untested implementation of the retry logic. It retries up to `numOfRetries` number of times, each retry is delayed by `delay` ms.

```js
var doWorkAsync = function (numOfRetries, delay) {
    var sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Table;";
    SQLite3JS.openAsync(path_to_db)
    .then(function (db) {
        return WinJS.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var nextStep = function () {
                db.runAsync(sql_query)
                .then(function (result) {
                    db.close();
                    resolve(result);
                }, function (error) {
                    if (--numOfRetries >= 0)
                        WinJS.Promise.timeout(delay).then(nextStep);
                    else
                    {
                        db.close();
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(new WinJS.ErrorFromName(error.name, error.message));
                    }
                });
            };
            nextStep();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I used as well, only without additional Promises and more by using substring() to check the error message for "database locked" and then a simple timeout set to 50 ms which simply called the function again.

However, I was searching for a more "elegant" solution :)

Comment: @Rhywden, no problem. If you find a more elegant solution, feel free to share it here as an answer.